# MVC route to capture file name as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to produce a simple WebDAV server using MVC, and I have finally reached the stage where I need to serve up a requested file to the user.

I have a route set up that deals with traversing the directory structure `"webdav/{*path}"` which works fine, right up until the point where that path ends in a file name. At this point, it appears that IIS decides that it is a static file, and attempts to serve that file from the disk. As it isn't in the location specified in the URL, it returns a 404 error.

I don't have any freedom to change the url, I basically need it to be in the form, otherwise Windows Explorer can't work with it as a mapped drive:

```
GET /webdav/Test/Test2.txt
```

I've set the route to greedily match, as the directory structure can have as many levels. I've also set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`

This is using IIS Express 8.0 on my development machine.

I've gone as far as setting up a blank MVC project just to test this, and this is the RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WebDAVGet",
    url: "webdav/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "WebDAV", action = "Get", path = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So, going to `/webdav/Test/Test2` hits the breakpoint in my controller, but going to `/webdav/Test/Test2.txt` gives me a 404.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to add this to the <system.webserver> node in web.config:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

I can vouch that this works on IIS 7.5.

For the record, I found this solution [here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html).

Comment: Yep, that's definitely a better way to do it!

Answer (score 12):

I needed to add

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

to the web config.

Ah, I've been struggling with this for a few days now, I knew posting here would shift the blockage!

Comment: perfect! exactly what i needed!