# How to pass a file path to an MVC Action as a parameter

Tags: c#, routes

I have a route and Controller and Action combo that successfully passes a string to the Action via javascript. If I try to pass a filename, e.g. test.png the action is not hit.

Whenever a filename/path is passed then the system tries to open/download the file - which makes sense.

Googling suggests editing the web.config file - as shown in this StackOverflow question: [MVC route to capture file name as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463021/mvc-route-to-capture-file-name-as-a-parameter).

I'm not sure this is the best solution - won't it effect any actual links to files that you may have - or will it be intelligent enough to know what you want?

I tried to create a solution whereby I replace the . in test.png to `<<dot>>` so I would be passing `test<<dot>>png` - This still didn't hit my action. So I thought I would try to encode the string using the Javascript `encodeURIComponent()` but that still doesn't hit my action - not sure why - All code is below - please could someone point out where I am going wrong - or put my mind at rest about using the solution linked to above.

Javascript:

```
$('#imageSelect').on('click', function () {
//pass selected image data to ActionResult function to process and create a div for
//unable to pass file name as it tries to open the file - so replace "." with "<<dot>>" and undo in the Action
var imagePathLocal = $('#tbImagePathLocal').val().replace(".", "<<dot>>");
var encodedImagePathLocal = encodeURIComponent(imagePathLocal);
$.ajax({
       async: false,
       url: '/Products/FilePath/CreateNewImage/' + encodedImagePathLocal
}).success(function (partialView) {
       $('#newImages').append(partialView);
   });
});
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult CreateNewImage(string filePath)
{
        //here I was going to unencode then
        //replace the "<<dot>>" with "."
        filePath = filePath.Replace("<<dot>>", ".");
}
```

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FilePathRoute",
    url: "{controller}/FilePath/{action}/{*filePath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", filePath = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Just to reiterate - the above code will work fine if the parameter was a string e.g. 'test' but as soon as I add the file extension 'test.png' it will fail.

Comment: You could consider changing the AJAX call from a GET to a POST - is that an option?

Comment: Could be an option - I'd prefer to keep it as GET for now if possible - just to keep everything as standard

Comment: @Henrik I changed to a POST and it works - not too familiar with Javascript/JQuery and just Googling my way through - Any explanation why POST works GET? Cheers.